# Safari ReferenceError: Can't find variable - What is going on

Tags: javascript, function, debugging, safari, onclick

Safari is throwing an error when i click the button
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: togglePopUp"

The function works fine in every other Browser (including IE)

Do you have any suggestions whats going on?

```
var formPopUp = document.querySelector('.form-popup');
var modalOpen = false;

var togglePopUp = function togglePopUp() {

  modalOpen = !modalOpen;
  formPopUp.classList.toggle('active');

  if (modalOpen) {
    document.querySelector('body').style = "overflow : hidden;";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('body').style = "overflow : auto;";
  }
};

var close = document.querySelector('.form-popup .close');

close.addEventListener('click', function () {
  togglePopUp();
});

window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == formPopUp) {
    togglePopUp();
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="togglePopUp()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function either by doing

```
function togglePopUp()
```

or using arrow notation

```
var togglePopUp = () => {...}
```